# Print a specific value in a new column depending on the value of another one

Tags: bash, awk

I need to print threshold to one file with awk , bash.

**file.txt**

```
device_1  200.33   1000.50
device_2  12.00    2000.11
device_3  400.22   6000.32
device_4  34.11    2000.11
```

I need to put a condition and print thresold(here is my trying):

```
cat file.txt |  awk '{if ($2 < 50); print $1, $2, $3, $4="97%" };elseif { ($2 > 50); print $1,$2,$3, $4="80%";}'
```

**"IF $2 < 50 , print 97% , else print 80% " :expected output**

```
device_1 200.33 1000.50 80%
device_2 12.00  2000.11 97%
device_3 400.22 6000.32 80%
device_4 34.11  2000.11 97%
```

It is not putting the right condition on column $2.

Comment: You immediately end the if with the semi colon. Should be `if(condition){do stuff}else if (condition){do stuff} else {do stuff}`.

Comment: and what about 50? it is not considered!

Comment: should be any value  lower than column $2, if value from column $2 is lower than 50 i can set an alarm based on that condition.

Answer (score 3):

[123 is right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47410818/column-2-lower-than-value-and-print-something-in-awk#comment81775207_47410818) about the proper construction of the if statement:

> You immediately end the if with the semi colon. Should be `if(condition){do stuff}else if (condition){do stuff} else {do stuff}`.

Still, since you are just going to print one value or another depending on the context, you can directly go for a ternary operator and say:

```
awk '{print $1, $2, $3, ($2 < 50 ? "97%" : "80%")}' file
```

Which outputs:

```
device_1 200.33 1000.50 80%
device_2 12.00 2000.11 97%
device_3 400.22 6000.32 80%
device_4 34.11 2000.11 97%
```

The expression `print $1, $2, $3, ($2 < 50 ? "97%" : "80%")` is saying: print $1, $2 and $3; then, another field consisting in either "97%" if $2 < 50 or "80%" otherwise.

Comment: I don't understand what you've explained here. Again, if $2 or 400.22 < than value 50 , print "space very low" , else "space ok".  According to value on second column i can set a print , if that value is lower than "one value set by me" , print something

Comment: @Slashlinux all of this you are saying is not explained in your question. Edit it to show your expected output, since now I see it is too broad.

Comment: You can exploit ("abuse") a feature of awk and simplify this to `awk '$4 = ($2 < 50) ? "80%" : "97%"' OFS=\\t input`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell good one! I may be a bit rusty now, I would've kung-fued this one some time ago :) Note, though, that if you set `$4 = 0` it won't trigger the `{print $0}`, so this does not output anything → `awk '$4 = ($2 < 50) ? "80%" : 0' file`.

Comment: @Slashlinux I see. But the idea remains the same, just try my code.

Comment: how can i remove ".200" from "400.22" value?

Comment: This is probably suited for another question, @Slashlinux